# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context (enum)

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift3

A little problem with an `enum`.

```
public enum LHActivityTypeID: String {
    case Run = "16"
    case Bike = "41"
}
```

Try to use it in an other file (yes my enum is global) :

```
if (activity.activity_type?.id  == .Bike ) {
    self?.allItems.append(activity)
}
```

> Error > Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I know that the `compiler` need more informations about the enum but i can't find how to do that, i've tried lot of thing et read some other post. Thank's for your help

Comment: What type is `id`, how it is declared?

Comment: id is a string.

Comment: Both new posted answers are correct. Two "Swift" conventions you should try: (1) Don't use parenthesis in your if statements unless needed - your's aren't - and (2) Enum case definitions no longer use capital letters.

Comment: @dfd reflex from other language, i note that, thank's !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the below.

```
if activity.activity_type?.id  == LHActivityTypeID.Bike.rawValue {
  self?.allItems.append(activity)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution !

Comment: Thank you @Mayke, it is my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is a string, you need to compare the `rawValue` of the enum

```
if activity.activity_type?.id  == LHActivityTypeID.Bike.rawValue {
    self?.allItems.append(activity)
}
```

PS: You don't need parentheses around an `if` condition in Swift.